# mysql query optimization with multiple groupings or order by

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

UPDATE: Table and index definition

```
desc activities;x
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+  
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default |  
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+  
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |  
| trackable_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |  
| trackable_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |  
| owner_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |  
| owner_type     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |  
| key            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |  
| parameters     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |  
| recipient_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |  
| recipient_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |  
| created_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |  
| updated_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |  
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+  

show indexes from activities;

+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+  
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                                            | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |  
+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+  
| activities |          0 | PRIMARY                                             |            1 | id             | A         |        7263 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type |            1 | trackable_id   | A         |        7263 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type |            2 | trackable_type | A         |        7263 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type         |            1 | owner_id       | A         |        7263 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type         |            2 | owner_type     | A         |        7263 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type |            1 | recipient_id   | A         |        2421 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
| activities |          1 | index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type |            2 | recipient_type | A         |        3631 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |  
+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+  

select count(id) from activities;  
+-----------+  
| count(id) |  
+-----------+  
|      7117 |  
+-----------+
```

This is what my current query looks like:

```
SELECT act.*, group_concat(act.owner_id order by act.created_at desc) as owner_ids 
FROM (select * from activities order by created_at desc) as act 
INNER JOIN users on users.id = act.owner_id 
WHERE (users.city_id = 1 and act.owner_type = 'User') 
GROUP BY trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type 
order by act.created_at desc 
limit 20 offset 0;
```

Doing an explain
[image: Explain]

I have played around with this query a lot including indexes etc. Is there any way to optimizes this query?

Comment: i think there is no use of `(select * from activities order by created_at desc)` subselect when you are selecting the whole data instead join directly by table name

Comment: I need to use that sub query before group_concat otherwise the results are not in the order I want.

Comment: No, you don't. That's why you have another order by in your group_concat function.

Comment: @HassanJaveed i agree with fancyPants

Comment: @fancyPants removing that subquery results in a different order of results.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @AndyLester updated question to include table and index definition.

Comment: First of all, read [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html): the ability to select "hidden" columns without aggregation is a MySQL-specific 'feature' that leads to indeterminate results (it is outright invalid in other RDBMS).  Perhaps you meant to `SELECT trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type, GROUP_BY(owner_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) ...`, which would make a bit more sense?  But if so, it's hard to see what you intend the outermost `ORDER BY` to accomplish (again, `created_at` is a "hidden" column that leads to indeterminate results).

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB or MyISAM? The `CREATE TABLE` output are more helpful than the DESCRIBE output.

Comment: Have you tried doing ANALYZE TABLE? Maybe the planner doesn't have up-to-date statistics.

Comment: Can you show the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE activities;` please ? will be easier for testing. `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL sometimes work weirdly so I will give this a shot. I'm assuming ID is Primary Key on users table.

```
SELECT 
    act.trackable_type, act.recipient_id, act.recipient_type,
max(act.created_at) as max_created_at,
    group_concat(act.owner_id order by act.created_at DESC) as owner_ids 
FROM  activities act 
WHERE act.owner_id in (select id from users where city_id = 1)
AND act.owner_Type = 'User'
GROUP BY trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type 
ORDER BY max_created_at
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: This seems to be fastest of all the solutions provided. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need `offset 0` at all, looks like you can live without subquery too. If you don't use fields from `users` table, you can use `in` (or `exists`) to make it clear:

```
select
    a.trackable_type, a.recipient_id, a.recipient_type,
    max(a.created_at) as max_created_at,
    group_concat(a.owner_id order by a.created_at desc) as owner_ids 
from activities as a
where
    a.owner_type = 'User' and
    a.owner_id in (select u.id from users as u where u.city_id = 1)
group by a.trackable_type, a.recipient_id, a.recipient_type
order by max_created_at desc
limit 20;
```

Also for me looks like your query could definitely get performance boost if you create index on `owner_type, owner_id` on `activities` (your index `owner_id, owner_type` will not work well for your query) and index on `city_id` on `users`.

Comment: @HassanJaveed so you can add offset to query. Don't know why did you accept nimdil answer, it's generally my answer but added one day later

Answer (score 0):

First i would start making the query more readable :-)

You don't need the Derived Table with ORDER BY and use a column list instead of ACT.*.

```
SELECT ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE, MAX(ACT.CREATED_AT) AS max_created,
   GROUP_CONCAT(ACT.OWNER_ID ORDER BY ACT.CREATED_AT DESC) AS OWNER_IDS 
FROM ACTIVITIES AS ACT 
JOIN USERS ON USERS.ID = ACT.OWNER_ID 
WHERE (USERS.CITY_ID = 1 AND ACT.OWNER_TYPE = 'USER') 
GROUP BY ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE
ORDER BY max_created DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Maybe it helps when you move the WHERE-condition on USERS into a Derived Table:

```
SELECT ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE, MAX(ACT.CREATED_AT) AS max_created,
   GROUP_CONCAT(ACT.OWNER_ID ORDER BY ACT.CREATED_AT DESC) AS OWNER_IDS 
FROM ACTIVITIES AS ACT 
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE CITY_ID = 1) USERS 
  ON USERS.ID = ACT.OWNER_ID 
WHERE ACT.OWNER_TYPE = 'USER'
GROUP BY ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE
ORDER BY max_created DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: I am going to these these two and get back to you :) THanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us the size of your users table, like the result of below query:

```
select count(id) from users WHERE users.city_id = 1;
```

If this is a small number, I suggest to use

```
SELECT act.trackable_type, act.recipient_id, act.recipient_type, max(act.created_at) as max_created_at,
    group_concat(act.owner_id order by act.created_at DESC) as owner_ids 
FROM  activities act 
WHERE act.owner_id in (select id from users where city_id = 1)
AND act.owner_Type = 'User'
GROUP BY trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type 
ORDER BY max_created_at
LIMIT 20
```

Otherwise, use join will be better

```
SELECT ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE, MAX(ACT.CREATED_AT) AS max_created_at,
   GROUP_CONCAT(ACT.OWNER_ID ORDER BY ACT.CREATED_AT DESC) AS OWNER_IDS 
FROM ACTIVITIES ACT 
JOIN USERS ON (USERS.CITY_ID = 1 AND USERS.ID = ACT.OWNER_ID)
WHERE ACT.OWNER_TYPE = 'USER'
GROUP BY ACT.TRACKABLE_TYPE, ACT.RECIPIENT_ID, ACT.RECIPIENT_TYPE
ORDER BY max_created DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, this is a very tricky query, and based on explainig what is meant and how to improve it, one can build an interesting interview for a developer position =).

1. MySQL uses [nested loop joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/nested-loop-joins.html), this means that when there is a join MySQL starts from a table and for each matching row in the table loops through relevant rows in the second table in the join.
2. When you have no indexes, then for each row MySQL goes on disk and fetches the fields which are used in conditions and does the same for each row in the other table. Going on disk is expensive and time-consuming, it is better to take information from the memory, so you can take the data from indexes.
3. The order of the join is selected by MySQL optimizer. But you can hint MySQL by creation of special indexes (and hints sometimes).
4. When you do things like this `(select * from activities order by created_at desc)` you load the whole table into a temporary unindexed table, which is hardly a good thing in any case. But the worst thing, is that MySQL should start the join from the table, because otherwise it would need to check a condition on each row of the table in a nested loop.
5. What does in mean to use an index for ordering or grouping (which requires sorting as well)? It means that you read the data in the order of an index. But since MySQL uses nested loops joins, you can only take advantage of an index for sorting when the table with the field you sort on are from the first table in the join.
6. the `created_at` field is not included into the `group by` clause, which means you do not care which from the group is picked (and they are probably the same within the group)
7. In complex queries, especially in those with pagination it is often better to select only the ids of the required rows and back-join the ids to the table for the rest of the fields (the less data you sort, the faster it takes).
8. to summarize, we need to start the join from `activities` table using an index, join to `users` in the nested loop and get the ids, and then back join to the activities table for the rest of the values.

Thus, you need rather long composite index on activities `(owner_type, trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type, owner_id, created_at)`, and a probably extravagant, but required index 
`(id, city_id)` on users.

Now, rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.id, group_concat(a.owner_id order by a.created_at desc) as owner_ids
   FROM activities a
   JOIN users u ON a.owner_id = u.id AND u.city_id = 1
   WHERE a.owner_type = 'User'
   GROUP BY trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type
   ORDER BY a.created_at desc
   limit 20 offset 0) as owners
JOIN activities a USING (id);
```

You should look at the EXPLAIN and probably and use STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of JOIN within the subquery to ensure the correct join order.

This solution seems a resource-demanding one, and it is. But it should be a good baseline for your following experiments. You should probably start with introducing some other fields for grouping (it is not efficient to have varchar 255 in the index, especially two of them), so you should thing of some sufficient prefixes, and either introduce them explicitly as sorters or force an index with prefixes. You might coin a special grouper field which is a function from (trackable_type, recipient_id, recipient_type) into something. This `owner_type = 'User'` is not that good either, it is better to compare integers, etc.